# Unable to solve ORA-06550 error pl/sql code

Tags: oracle, select, plsql

I see that there are a couple of similar questions but non of the answers were able to solve my problems and that is why I am posting the code here. I appreciate the help. When I run the code I am getting:

```
ORA-06550: line 23, column 25:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 23, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

create table city
(cityid numeric(10),
cityname varchar2(20),
cityregion varchar(20),
citypopulation INT,
constraint city_pk primary key (cityid));


declare
c_id  number := 0 ;
c_name varchar2(30) ;
c_region varchar2(30);
c_pop number;
time_now timestamp;
time_after timestamp;
cityid_copy city.cityid%type;

begin
while (c_id <= 3000)
loop
c_name    := 'City' || c_id;
c_region  := 'Region' || c_id;
c_pop     := c_id + 500;
INSERT INTO city
(cityid,cityname,cityregion,citypopulation)
values(c_id,c_name,c_region,c_pop);
c_id := c_id +1;
end loop;
time_now := systimestamp;
select cityid from city into cityid_copy
where cityid = 1;
time_after := systimestamp;
Dbms_Output.Put_Line((time_after)- (time_now));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't quite got the syntax of a PL/SQL `SELECT ... INTO ...` statement right.  The variables you are selecting into must come before the `FROM` clause.

To fix your error, replace this line

```
select cityid from city into cityid_copy
```

with this line

```
select cityid into cityid_copy from city
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I finally figured it out.  The INTO clause should follow immediately after the projection: select cityid into cityid_copy from city